# Ruin Probability: Algebraic proof that entering a casino at time $1$ with $X_1=k\pm 1$ or at time $0$ with $X_0=k\pm 1$ makes no difference.

Tags: probability, independence

Consider a game in which two players $A$ and $B$ share an amount of S dollars and at each round player $A$ may earn 1 dollar with probability $p$ and in this case $B$ loses 1 dollar. Let $X_n$ represent the wealth of player $A$ at time $n$. We consider the ruin probability $R_A = \bigcup_n \{X_n= 0\}$.

I am looking at the proof that for all $k=1,\dots ,S-1$ we have 
$$\mathbb{P}(R_A | X_1 = k \pm 1, X_0=k) = \mathbb{P}(R_A | X_1 = k \pm 1) = \mathbb{P}(R_A | X_0 = k \pm 1).$$

However, in the below proof, I don't understand why $P(\{X_1 = k\pm 1\} \cap \{X_1-X_0 = \pm 1\})=P(X_1 = k\pm 1) P(X_1-X_0=\pm 1)$, i.e. $\{X_1 = k\pm 1\}$ and $\{X_1 - X_0 = \pm 1\}$ are independent events. I can't think of a logical reason or an algebraif proof of this. I would greatly appreciate some help here.

[image]

[image]